Scene builder installation
I wan to install latest version of scene builder of 21 I did have version build 16 I tried to uninstall it but it told me it needed the installer package which I deleted long ago now I am trying to install latest version of 21 and it tells me the same problem it needs an install package which I deleted it  what can I do ?
